# How to print disassembly registers in the Xcode console

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb, disassembly

I'm looking at some disassembly code and see something like `0x01c8f09b  <+0015>  mov    0x8(%edx),%edi` and I am wondering what the value of `%edx` or `%edi` is.

Is there a way to print the value of `%edx` or other assembly variables?  Is there a way to print the value at the memory address that `%edx` points at (I'm assuming `edx` is a register containing a pointer to ... something here).

For example, you can print an objet by typing `po` in the console, so is there a command or syntax for printing registers/variables in the assembly?

Background:

I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on this line and I would like to debug what is going on.  I'm aware this error is related to memory management and I'm looking at figuring out where I may be missing/too-many retain/release/autorelease calls.

Additional Info:

This is on IOS, and my application is running in the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can print a register (e.g, `eax`) using:

```
print $eax
```

Or for short:

```
p $eax
```

To print it as hexadecimal:

```
p/x $eax
```

To display the value pointed to by a register:

```
x $eax
```

Check the gdb help for more details:

```
help print
help x
```

Answer (score 13):

Depends up which Xcode compiler/debugger you are using. For gcc/gdb it's

```
info registers
```

but for clang/lldb it's

```
register read
```

Answer (score 9):

```
(gdb) info reg
eax            0xe  14
ecx            0x2844e0 2639072
edx            0x285360 2642784
ebx            0x283ff4 2637812
esp            0xbffff350   0xbffff350
ebp            0xbffff368   0xbffff368
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x80483f9    0x80483f9 <main+21>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

From [Debugging with gdb](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gdb_10.html#SEC63):

> You can refer to machine register contents, in expressions, as variables with names 
>   starting with `$'. The names of registers are different for each machine; use info 
>   registers to see the names used on your machine.
>
> ```
> info registers
> ```
>
> Print the names and values of all registers except floating-point
>   registers (in the selected stack frame).
>
> ```
> info all-registers
> ```
>
> Print the names and values of all registers, including floating-point
>   registers.
>
> ```
> info registers regname ...
> ```
>
> Print the relativized value of each specified register regname.
>   regname may be any register name valid on the machine you are using,
>   with or without the initial `$'.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using LLDB instead of GDB you can use `register read`

Answer (score 3):

Those are not variables, but registers.

In GDB, you can see the values of standard registers by using the following command:

```
info registers
```

Note that a register contains integer values (32bits in your case, as the register name is prefixed by `e`). What it represent is not known. It can be a pointer, an integer, mostly anything.

If `po` crashes when you try to print a register's value as a pointer, it's likely that the value is not a pointer (or an invalid one).